# Adding a tuple to a set does not work

Tags: scala, set, tuples

```
scala> val set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[(Int, Int)]()
set: scala.collection.mutable.Set[(Int, Int)] = Set()

scala> set += (3, 4)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: (Int, Int)
              set += (3, 4)
                  ^

scala> set += Tuple2(3, 4)
res5: set.type = Set((3,4))
```

Adding `(3, 4)` does not work - why ?

Normally, `(3, 4)` also represents a tuple with two elements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue is that it exists in the `Set` trait a method `+(elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A+)` and the compiler is confused by it. It actually believes that you try to use this method with 2 `Int` parameters instead of using it with a tuple, as expected.

You can use instead: `set += (3 -> 4)` or `set += ((3, 4))`

Comment: Arggh :) What's the meaning of the brackets and -> in the first option? And what are the doubled-up brackets actually saying in the second?

Comment: (Ok so -> is arrowAssoc and forms a relation between the two arguments expressed as a tuple http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html)