# Scala - tuple type inference fail?

Tags: scala, tuples, type-inference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a tuple to a set does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825765/adding-a-tuple-to-a-set-does-not-work)

I have this code:

```
class A

var buffer = Buffer[(A, Int)]()
```

then, somewhere:

```
val a = new A
buffer += (a, 0) // error
```

the type inferencer fails on `a` in `(a, 0)` telling that I pass `A` when I must pass `(A, Int)`:

```
scala> def make {
     | val a = new A
     | buffer += (a, 0)
     | }
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: (A, Int)
       buffer += (a, 0)
              ^
```

however if I do this:

```
val a = new A
val tuple = (a, 0)
buffer += tuple
```

the error is gone. Is this some kind of bug or am I missing something?

Comment: It's not a set here, but the issue is exactly the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler does not know, whether you mean buffer.+=(a,0) or buffer += Tuple2(a,0) here.

possible solutions:

```
buffer += Tuple2(a, 0)

buffer += Pair(a, 0) // Pair is an alias for Tuple2

buffer += ((a, 0))

buffer += a -> 0
```

Comment: chosing this answer for the greatest variety of options, namely, specifying the `Pair` and `Tuple2` options, which is beneficial for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the compiler's message is somewhat misleading. The point is that `buffer += (a, 0)` gets desugared to `buffer.+=(a, 0)`, which is as you can see a call to a two parameter function `+=`. What you need is a single parameter function, so to solve your issue either simply put your tuple in extra braces like so:

```
 buffer += ((a, 0))
```

or use a sugarred pair syntax like so:

```
 buffer += (a -> 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that += is just a function call at the end. The function "+=" has the following signature:

```
abstract def +=(elem: A): Buffer.this.type
```

So the compiler will interprete the following as if you are passing two arguments to the "+=" function as opposed to passing a tuple to it.

```
buffer += (a, 0) // error
```

Solution is to have a nested parenthesis thus making clear to the compiler that you are passing a tuple as:

```
scala> buffer += ((new A(), 0))
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[(A, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((A@16fe464e,0), (A@6774c043,0))
```